# Restore local git repo that you committed but didn’t push

Tags: git

As the title says.

I made a new repo added all the stuff, committed it but didn’t push to remote then deleted it by accident…

Is there a way to restore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you either have a backup or are lucky enough to be able to recover it from your filesystem (which may be very unlikely and/or involve much more effort than restarting your work over).

Comment: Oh well I thought so